# How do we bind the text in CKEditor to the underlying textarea?

Tags: ckeditor, alpacajs

I am using Alpaca to render the CKEditor. When I post the form, changes in the editor is not saved. What is the best way to make CKEditor update the text to the underlying textarea field? I do not find this explained in any of the documentation.

Is there a good way to fetch the editor content so I could manually update the field before I post the form?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle for that or a portion of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Use [updateElement()](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-updateElement) to update the textarea field with CKEditor data.

> Updates the  element that was replaced by the editor with
>   the current data available in the editor.
>
> Note: This method will only affect those editor instances created with
>   the CKEDITOR.ELEMENT_MODE_REPLACE element mode or inline instances
>   bound to  elements.
>
> CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.updateElement();